# How to access var from parent class inside a static function

Tags: php, class, static-members

How do I access the vars from the parents class inside a static class/function?

(still a noob when it comes to oop and php ;-))

Small example

```
class database{

    public $dbTable = 'mysqltable';

}  

class install extends database{

    public static function getTable(){
         $this->dbTable;// not working
         self::dbTable;// not working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **parent::** and make sure your variable from your extending class is also defined as **static**.

Following should work:

```
class database{

    public static $dbTable = 'mysqltable';

}  

class install extends database{

    public static function getTable(){
         parent::$dbTable;// working
    }
}
```

Comment: Seen it and even when Ill add the word static the error is still there.

Comment: Did you add the **$** sign? parent::$dbTable;

Answer (score 0):

Accessing instance variables from static methods isn't supported in PHP.

If you make $dbTable static (change `public $dbTable = 'mysqltable';` to `public static $dbTable = 'mysqltable';`), you'll be able to access it from your static getTable() method like this: `parent::$dbTable;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the property static to access it form a static method. $this is not available from static methods. If you do that, you can access the static method via self or parent:

```
class database
{
   public static $dbTable = 'mysqltable';
}

class install extends database
{
    public static function getTable()
    {
         return array(self::$dbTable, parent::$dbTable);
    }
}
var_dump(install::getTable());
```